# JQuery "append" hangs the page

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(Data, function (i, item) {
             //debugger;
             var newrow = $(".hide").clone();
             $(newrow).find(".hdnID").val(item.ID);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnSecID").val(item.SecID);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnSno").val(item.SNO);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnMchID").val(item.MchId);
             $(newrow).find(".MchDesc").html(item.MchDesc);
             $(newrow).find(".jobdesc").html(item.JobDesc);
             $(newrow).find(".SecName").html(item.SecName);
             Index++;
             console.log(Index);


             $("#Acdetail").append($(newrow));


         });
```

There are `250` items that need to be appended. But it hangs the page. If I remove  `$("#Acdetail").append($(newrow));` and just print the html of new row using `console.log` it will print with in 2 seconds.

Any help?

Comment: 250 isn't a very high number to make the hang happen. How many `$('.hide')` elements do you have on the page?

Comment: Are you sure it's   $("#Acdetail").append($(newrow)); and not   $("#Acdetail").append(newrow) that you have to do?

Comment: @NadeemAamir: You have a **lot** of pointless calls to `$()` there. `newrow` refers to a jQuery set. You don't need to use `$()` around it. (It's not the problem, but as it's clearly a habit...) If you *did* need it, it would be best to do it **once** rather than on every line.

Comment: @agfc yes it $("#Acdetail").append($(newrow));

Comment: When the `$.each` iterates at its last iteration, the `$(".hide")` will return elements with count similar to Data's.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok I will keep in mind next time. I have changed it to $("#Acdetail").append(newrow) but the result is same

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I did not understand your point can you please tell me in detail

Comment: @asprin Thanks for correcting my english mistake. :)

Comment: @NadeemAamir Uh? When did I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **re-cloning** previously-appended elements every time the `each` callback is called (by searching for all matching `.hide` elements each time). So on the first pass, maybe you just have one so you append one; on the next pass, you have two and so you append two; on the third pass you have **four** so you append four; on the fourth pass, you have **eight** so you append eight. And so on. Assuming you start with just one, you'll end up with 250! (250 [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)) elements, which is a **massively high** number: 3.23285626E+492

You probably don't want to do that.

Probably best to make an initial clone and then reclone it, rather than re-searching the DOM for all `.hide` elements.

Also, you have a **lot** of unnecessary calls to `$()` there.

This addresses both problems:

```
var clone = $(".hide").clone();
$.each(Data, function(i, item) {
    //debugger;
    var newrow = clone.clone();
    newrow.find(".hdnID").val(item.ID);
    newrow.find(".hdnSecID").val(item.SecID);
    newrow.find(".hdnSno").val(item.SNO);
    newrow.find(".hdnMchID").val(item.MchId);
    newrow.find(".MchDesc").html(item.MchDesc);
    newrow.find(".jobdesc").html(item.JobDesc);
    newrow.find(".SecName").html(item.SecName);
    Index++;
    console.log(Index);
    $("#Acdetail").append(newrow);
});
```

And in fact, better to do the append only at the end, when you're done:

```
var clone = $(".hide").clone();
var toAppend = $();
$.each(Data, function(i, item) {
    //debugger;
    var newrow = clone.clone();
    newrow.find(".hdnID").val(item.ID);
    newrow.find(".hdnSecID").val(item.SecID);
    newrow.find(".hdnSno").val(item.SNO);
    newrow.find(".hdnMchID").val(item.MchId);
    newrow.find(".MchDesc").html(item.MchDesc);
    newrow.find(".jobdesc").html(item.JobDesc);
    newrow.find(".SecName").html(item.SecName);
    Index++;
    console.log(Index);
    toAppend = toAppend.add(newrow);
});
toAppend.appendTo("#Acdetail");
```

If you're ever going to run this code a second time, you'll need to do something to filter out the previous `.hide` elements (perhaps remove the class).

Comment: Nice catch. I failed to see the issue there. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
         $.each(Data, function (i, item) {

             var newrow = $(".hide").clone();
             $(newrow).find(".hdnID").val(item.ID);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnSecID").val(item.SecID);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnSno").val(item.SNO);
             $(newrow).find(".hdnMchID").val(item.MchId);
             $(newrow).find(".MchDesc").html(item.MchDesc);
             $(newrow).find(".jobdesc").html(item.JobDesc);
             $(newrow).find(".SecName").html(item.SecName);
             Index++;

             $(newrow).removeClass("hide").addClass('sectr');
             $("#Acdetail").append(newrow);

         });
```

Issue has been resolved after  $(newrow).removeClass("hide").addClass('sectr'); actually the problem was too many clone of (.hide).